# How to extract out information separated by a character from a column?

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line

I have a file `data` like this:

```
head data

19  54240283    .   T   C   .   .   .    188,18:208:14:102:18:189:209:37.7222:37.4681:9:139:9:50:50.8889:40.3545:919.145:640.562:0
1   103020      .   A   C   .   .   .    1,2:3:2:2:2:2:4:38:38:2:2:0:0:46.5:28:0.5:162:0
2   8797402     .   G   A   .   .   .    0,3:3:3:0:3:0:3:38:0:0:3:0:38.3333:840.056:0
```

The most important information is hidden at the 9th column (longest one), right between the 4th and 6th `:`. For example:

```
19  54240283    .   T   C   .   .   .    18:189
1   103020      .   A   C   .   .   .    2:2
2   8797402     .   G   A   .   .   .    3:0
```

Finally, I would like to extract them out and create new columns for them. For example,

```
19  54240283    .   T   C   .   .   .    18    189
1   103020      .   A   C   .   .   .    2     2
2   8797402     .   G   A   .   .   .    3     0
```

Could anyone help me figure out how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]+|:' '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$13,$14 }' data | column -t
```

The output:

```
19  54240283  .  T  C  .  .  .  18  189
1   103020    .  A  C  .  .  .  2   2
2   8797402   .  G  A  .  .  .  3   0
```

---

- `-F'[[:space:]]+|:'` - whitespace(s) and `:` are considered as field separator

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's|\d+,(\S+)$|join "\t", (split /:/, $1)[4,5]|e' data
```

---

### Result

```
19  54240283    .   T   C   .   .   .    18     189
1   103020      .   A   C   .   .   .    2      2
2   8797402     .   G   A   .   .   .    3      0
```